# How to draw sketch lines with C# and GDI+

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, gdi+

Is it possible to draw lines and figures like shown below in GDI+ and c#?

[image]

May be there is some way to do that in easy way in c#?

Update:
I mean that I need to imitate Hand-Drawing effect in GDI+
I would like to write something like:

```
graphics.DrawHandDrawnLine(Pens.Black, x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

and see something like this

[image: hand drawn line]

Comment: GDI+ has all the APIs like DrawRectangle, DrawLine, DrawString etc. depending on what and where you want to draw.

Comment: Yes, I know, Thanks. I think I found what I need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370199/creating-a-hand-drawn-effect-using-net

Comment: Forget winforms. You're looking for [SketchFlow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/ee215229.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will be hard to top in the 'more easy' department..:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Doodle
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    List<Point> curPoints = new List<Point>();
    List<List<Point>> allPoints = new List<List<Point>>();

    private void pnlPaint_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (curPoints.Count > 1)
        {
            // begin fresh line
            curPoints.Clear();
            // startpoint
            curPoints.Add(e.Location);
        }
    }

    private void pnlPaint_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (curPoints.Count > 1)
        {
            // ToList creates a copy
            allPoints.Add(curPoints.ToList());
            curPoints.Clear();
        }


    }

    private void pnlPaint_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;
        // here we should check if the distance is more than a minimum!
        curPoints.Add(e.Location);
        // let it show
        pnlPaint.Invalidate();
    }
    private void pnlPaint_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3f))
        {
            // regular edges:
            pen.MiterLimit = 1.5f
            // current lines
            if (curPoints.Count > 1) e.Graphics.DrawCurve(pen, curPoints.ToArray());
            // other lines
            foreach (List<Point> points in allPoints)
                if (points.Count > 1) e.Graphics.DrawCurve(pen, points.ToArray());
        }
    }}

    private void btn_undo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (allPoints.Count > 0)
        {
            allPoints.RemoveAt(allPoints.Count - 1);
            pnlPaint.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = @"d:\sketch.png";
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pnlPaint.ClientSize.Width, pnlPaint.ClientSize.Width);
        pnlPaint.DrawToBitmap(bmp, pnlPaint.ClientRectangle);
        bmp.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
  }

  class DrawPanel : Panel 
  {
     public DrawPanel ()
      {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
      }
  }

}
```

Just add one DrawPanel and two Buttons..

[image]

(I really should have used my Wacom, and a little more space..)

---

**Update:** Instead of a `Panel`, which is a `Container` control and not really meant to draw onto you can use a `Picturebox` or a `Label` (with `Autosize=false`); both have the `DoubleBuffered` property turned on out of the box and support drawing better than `Panels` do.

Comment: Of course, since we are keeping the points in lists we can apply all sort of Transformations to them. Paste this into  the beginning of the `Paint` event: `Matrix matrix = new Matrix();     matrix.Scale((float) nud_zoom.Value / 100f, (float)nud_zoom.Value / 100f);   e.Graphics.MultiplyTransform(matrix);`  now add a `NumericUpDown` with an `pnlPaint.Invalidate();` in its `ValueChanged` event and you can scale the Drawing..

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution [Creating a Hand-Drawn effect using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370199/creating-a-hand-drawn-effect-using-net)

Maybe there is something more easy, for example something with transformations?

Comment: I mean **Graphics.TransformPoints** and similar methods from **Graphics**

Comment: See my comment above. It would help to know just what you want to achieve beyond simple doodling